# Crash QGis 2.16 by defining a memory vector layer with python

Tags: qgis, python

With a python plugin for QGis 2.16, i try to define a new temporary layer:

```
vl = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon", "temporary_lay", "memory")
```

as shown here:
http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/vector.html

but executing this line, QGis crash with a segmentation error message. Same error with any string for the uri.
Then i tried to define the uri with:

```
uri = QgsDataSourceURI()
uri.setParam("url", "polygon")
uri.setParam('crs', "EPSG:32632")
vl = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), "temporary_lay", "memory")
print memoryLayer.isValid()
```

but the print command return "False" (layer non valid).

Anyone knows the correct syntax for defining a temporary memory layer with QGis 2.16?

Comment: Did you import the relevant modules such as `from PyQt4.QtCore import *`; `from PyQt4.QtGui import *`; `from qgis.core import *` etc?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that first `QgsVectorLayer` line. It should work in a plugin and not segfault. Does it segfault if you run it in the Qgis Python console rather than in a plugin?

Comment: If i run the code in the Python console it works!

Comment: Solved! the command is correct but was run concurrently with the creation of other levels. 
Thanks Spacedman for the helpful advice!